# Dynamically change Login/Logout button based on status

Tags: php, dynamic, authentication, logout

I want the navbar to either display "Admin" and "Logout" if the user is logged in, or "Log In" and "Register" if no user is logged in.

So far it's always showing Login and Register. It does keep the login, because I can't visit the login/register pages (I've made it so a logged in user gets redirected to home).

My REGISTER id is just text styling.

Login snippet:

```
if(isset($_POST["login"])){
$username = trim($_POST['username']);
$username = strip_tags($username);
$username = htmlspecialchars($username);

$password = trim($_POST['password']);
$password = strip_tags($password);
$password = htmlspecialchars($password);


$loginQuery= "SELECT * FROM members where username='$username' AND password=PASSWORD('$password')";
$result= mysqli_query($conn, $loginQuery);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)){
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    header("Location: index.php");
}
else{
    $loginErrorExists= TRUE;
}
```

}

Homepage snippet:

```
<?php
        if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
            echo "<a id=\"register\" class=\"header-button\" href=\"admin.php\"><span class=\"bold small-white-subtitle\">Dashboard</span></a>";
            echo "<a id=\"register\" class=\"header-button\" href=\"logout.php\"><span class=\"bold small-white-subtitle\">Logout</span></a>";
        }
        else{
            echo "<a id=\"register\" class=\"header-button\" href=\"login.php\"><span class=\"bold small-white-subtitle\">Log In</span></a>";
            echo "<a id=\"register\" class=\"header-button\" href=\"register.php\"><span class=\"bold small-white-subtitle\">Register</span></a>";
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: Where is your `session_start` ? you should learn about [sessions](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp)

Comment: Have you remebered to use session_start() at top of page?

Comment: Both pages have session_start(). It does show Login Register, but it remembers the login.

Comment: sql injection alert :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add extra field and put 1 or 0 in admin login and then check with 0 or 1 in view page

Comment: I don't need to differentiate between admins and regular users. All users are admins. I just want it to make my code remember that someone did log in at all.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you are looking for:

```
$loginQuery= "SELECT * FROM members where username='$username' ";
$result= mysqli_query($conn, $loginQuery);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$pass = $row['password'];

$check = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($check = 0){
   if($pass){
      $_SESSION['role'] = $row['role'];
      $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
      header("Location: index.php");
   }
}else{
  echo('Invalid Username or Password ');
  exit;
}
```

In your Index.php

```
<?session_start();    
.....
If(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
 echo $_SESSION['role']; echo "$logout";
}else{
 echo <a href="$register">REGISTER</a>
}
```

I change a bit of your code, for security purposes and hope this would work. You can get the flow of the code and where its heading so you can add more to it.